# Query on installating CPAN modules in linux OS

Tags: perl

We developed scripts which are running in windows now(strawberry perl). If I want to run same scripts in linux(I' using some cpan modules), Do I need to change anything?

Comment: That depends entirely on what you're doing. If you're, say, using the win32 API to access COM objects, then yes. If you're processing plain text, probably not. If you're doing something in the middle, then the answer is "maybe".

Comment: Thanks for quick reply Wooble                                                 I'm using DBI, FILE::FETCH, SSH::COMMAND and THREADING. I'm fetching files from remote server and Querying DB in local server.

Comment: Assuming the database is something you run on the local linux machine too, I'd say threading would be most likely to cause you problems; there are areas where threads on Windows are different. I'd try running your script on a linux box and see what breaks. :)

Answer (score 1):

After the shebang, add these lines:

`use strict;`

`use warnings; #or add -w to the shebang`

If you run your script with those lines on the Linux system, Perl will helpfully tell you that it cannot find a module/dependency, if there are any problems.  If they are not already in the windows version, then there might be a lot of warnings given and fixes needed.

http://perldoc.perl.org/perllexwarn.html

http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=111088

http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html

Update:  as Rick mentions in a reply, the shebang line itself will also need to be changed to something *like* `#!/usr/local/bin/perl` or `#!/usr/bin/perl`

Comment: In general, I find moving Perl code from Windows to LINUX rather easy once you adjust the bang lines and file paths in your code. Going in the other direction, however, is much more difficult due to Windows lack of POSIX features and thread/fork handling issues. Module development seems to be more active on non-Windows systems so unless you are using something Windows specific you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on exactly what your scripts do you may not have to change anything, but without doubt you must run through your entire test suite on Linux. If anything fails you will then know where the problem is.

It could be that you've written some OS specific code, and will need to cater for certain parts differently under each OS.

It could be that there are bugs for modules which you use for one platform but not the other.

So the answer is that nobody can tell you, because you'd have to post all of your code and expect someone to test it on multiple OS, which is unreasonable.

The real answer is that you have to do some work to dertermine what must be done. At the mimimum run your whole test suite.

Comment: And step 0 is to make sure you have a decent test suite.